# Any C#/VB.NET sample projects on developing ActiveX Documents(?) to be hosted by MS Word 2000-2010?

Tags: ms-word, activex, hosting, document

Do you know about any helpful C#/VB.NET sample projects on developing ActiveX Documents(?) to be hosted by MS Word 2000-2010?

I mean a C#/VB.NET sample project having ActiveX Document project/solution sources, which can be compiled, built and registered, and then ActiveX Document instance inserted inline several times into an MS Word document by using

Insert -> 
 Object MS Word (2003) menu -> 
   Create New tab -> 
      select custom ActiveX Document from the list -> 
         Cick [OK] button -> 
              Get ActiveX Document instance inserted into MS Word doc...

Thank you.